# htaccess Digest authentication

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection, digest-authentication, .htpasswd

I'd like to protect a folder by .htaccess. The following doesn't work. It displays the login dialog in a browser, but it looks as if the username and password don't match. When I changed the method to Basic, it worked fine.

```
AuthUserFile /home/pass/.htpasswd
AuthName "Login"
AuthType Digest
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The digest authentication method uses a different type of password file. You can't use a password file generated for BASIC to use with DIGEST. You need to use the [`htdigest` command](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htdigest.html) (or some equivalent online digest file generator) to create the password file.